# Spring-Boot-Maven-Plugin issue "could not transfer"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin

I have got an issue with a cloned project:

Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin/2.1.7.RELEASE/spring-boot-maven-plugin-2.1.7.RELEASE.pom

This occurred when I tried to clean build my maven project in IntelliJ

Comment: Could you share your simplified version of pom.xml?

Comment: Do you have access to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like you don't have a proxy in your settings.xml. Take a look [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html) for details on how to set it up.

```
<proxies>
   <proxy>
      <id>example-proxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.example.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>www.google.com|*.example.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
```

You should be able to take the proxy details from your browser settings.